# Помогите оптимизировать код!

Tags: python, алгоритм, оптимизация

**Условие:**
Директор школы доверил провести линейку учителю математики, но тот воспринял это задание буквально и выстроил всех учеников школы в одну длинную линию. Увидев это директор решил оценить такое построение, вычислив две характеристики:
**Болтливость построения.**
Директор предположил, что ученики одного класса будут болтать между собой. Поэтому его интересует суммарное попарное расстояние между учениками одинаковых классов.
**Задирчивость построения.**
Директор предположил, что ученики разных классов будут задирать друг друга. Поэтому его интересует суммарное попарное расстояние между учениками разных классов.
Ваша задача — вычислить болтливость и задирчивость построения.\

**Замечание**:
В примере болтливость складывается из расстояний: |1 − 4| + |2 − 3|, а задирчивость — из расстояний: |1−2|+|1−3|+|2−4|+|3−4|.\

**Формат входных данных**
Первая строка содержит одно целое положительное число K (1 <= K <= 105) — число классов в школе.
Следующая строка содержит одно целое положительное число N (1 <= N <= 105) — число учеников в школе, которые пришли на линейку.
Следующие N строк содержат описания учеников участвующих в линейке. Каждая из этих N строк содержит описание одного ученика: два целых числа x и y (|x| <= 107,1 <= y <= K) — положение ученика и его класс.\

Формат выходных данных
В первой строке выведите одно целое число — болтливость построения.
Во второй строке выведите одно целое число — задирчивость построения.\

**Пример 1**
Входные данные:
2
4
1 1
2 2
3 2
4 1
Выходные данные:
4
6
**Ограничения:**
1 секунда времени на выполнение
**Мой код:**

```py
k = int(input())    #Количество классов
n = int(input())    #Количество учеников
students = list([list(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(n)])

classes=[[i[0] for i in students if i[1]==j] for j in range(1, k+1)]

talkative=sum([sum([sum([abs(num1-num2) for num1 in classes[clas]]) for num2 in classes[clas-1]]) for clas in range(k)])//2
bullying=sum([sum([sum([abs(num1-num2) for num1 in clas]) for num2 in clas]) for clas in classes])//2
print(talkative)
print(bullying)
```

**Проблема:** выполнение кода занимает слишком много времени, как его оптимизировать????

Comment: убери из кода то, что не относится к задаче

Comment: Можете, кстати, задать вопрос на [code-review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), там вам помогут наверняка.

Comment: зачем создавать numpy-массив и не использовать ни одной его функции? Зачем давать переменным имена, из которых ничего непонятно? Что такое q, p и s?

Comment: Понял, вот код без лишнего и понятными именами:```k = int(input())    #Количество классов
n = int(input())    #Количество учеников
students = list([list(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(n)])

classes=[[i[0] for i in students if i[1]==j] for j in range(1, k+1)]

talkative=sum([sum([sum([abs(num1-num2) for num1 in classes[clas]]) for num2 in classes[clas-1]]) for clas in range(k)])//2
bullying=sum([sum([sum([abs(num1-num2) for num1 in clas]) for num2 in clas]) for clas in classes])//2
print(talkative)
print(bullying)```

Comment: под вопросом есть кнопка "Править". Код в комментариях невозможно читать вообще, а питонский особенно.

Comment: поправил, спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Отсортировав студентов и разбив позиции по классам, получаем список списков такого вида (думаю, это то, что у вас в classes)

```
[[1,3,4,9],[2,7],[5,6,8]]
```

Посчитаем для каждого подсписка сумму длин внутренних связей (добавляется к inner) - это будет болтливость. Почему так считается - каждый промежуток между соседними позициями участвует в сумме `(left+1)*(right+1)` раз, где left и right - количество позиций слева и справа от промежутка.

Edit: Как заметил Stanislav Volodarskiy, координаты не обязательно идут подряд, поэтому сумму длин общих связей всех элементов `overall` считаем аналогичным образом в общем строю.

А сумма длин внешних связей  (задиристость) есть общая длина минус внутренние

```
k=3
students = [[5,3],[6,3],[7,2],[10,3],[12,1],[1,1],[2,2],[3,1],[4,1]]
n = len(students)
students.sort()

overall = 0
classes = [[] for _ in range(k)]
for i in range(n):
    if i:
        overall += (students[i][0] - students[i-1][0])*i*(n-i)
    classes[students[i][1]-1].append(students[i][0])
print(classes)

inner = 0
for cl in classes:
    lencl = len(cl)
    for i in range(1, lencl):
        inner += (cl[i] - cl[i-1])*i*(lencl-i)

print(inner)
outer = overall - inner
print(outer)
```

Результат:

```
[[1, 3, 4, 12], [2, 7], [5, 6, 10]]
49
107
```

Comment: алгоритм хороший, но всё ещё очень медленный

Comment: Вообще-то без учёта сортировки он линейный, быстрее ничего не будет

Comment: Вот что - вы данные долго готовите, создавая список classes квадратичным алгоритмом. Просто создайте список k пустых подсписков и распихивайте в них каждого студента по очереди

Comment: Строй учеников не обязан быть плотным. `overall` нужно считать по тем же правилам что и `inner`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Хм, действительно - разные ограничения на N и x такие варианты не исключают. Ну что ж, дорожка уже проложена.